# Shuffle text inside HTML elements

Tags: php, html-parsing, shuffle

I´m trying to shuffle articles with the PHP-shuffle function and with the [Simple HTML Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).

For example, this is my content:

```
<p>This is my article.</p>
<h2>This is a subheading</h2>
<p>This is an paragraph with an image inside it <img src="http://image.jpg">
</p>
```

The output should be something like this:

```
<p>article is This my .</p>
<h2>This subheading is a</h2>
<p>is an  with an image paragraph inside This it <img src="http://image.jpg"></p>
```

However, using the Simple HTML DOM parser, I find it difficult to prevent the images from being shuffeled because they sometimes are placed inside paragraphs.

This is my current script. I feel like it is way to complicated, and it sometimes doesn't output the correct result.

Hopefully someone can help me.

```
    $tags           = 'p, ul, ol, blockquote, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7';

    $html           = str_get_html( $html );

    /**
     * Loop through HTML and set output 
     */
    foreach( $html->find( $tags ) as $article ) {

        $element    = $article->outertext;
        $array      = $article;
        $tag        = $article->tag;
        $innerHTML  = '';

        // Nested paragraphs
        foreach ( $array->find('p') as $el ){

            $word_array = preg_replace( "#[\s]+#", " ", $el->innertext );
            $words      = explode( " ", $word_array );
            $w          = '';

            shuffle( $words );

            foreach ( $words as $word ){
                $w .= $word . ' ';
            }

            $innerHTML .= $el->innertext = $w;

        }

        // List items
        foreach ( $array->find('li') as $el ){

            $word_array = preg_replace( "#[\s]+#", " ", $el->innertext );
            $words      = explode( " ", $word_array );
            $w          = '';

            shuffle( $words );

            foreach ( $words as $word ){
                $w .= $word . ' ';
            }

            $innerHTML .= $el->innertext = '<li>' . $w . '</li>';

        }

        // Images
        foreach ( $array->find('img') as $el ) {

            // Blur image
            $src      = stripslashes( str_replace( '"', '', $el->src ) );
            $new_src  = $this->create_blur_image( $src );

            // Replace url with base64 encode
            $src        = $el->src = $new_src;

            $innerHTML .= $el->outertext;

        }

        // Output
        if ( $innerHTML ){
            $element = $article->innertext = $innerHTML;

        } else {

            $word_array = preg_replace( "#[\s]+#", " ", $article->innertext );
            $words      = explode( " ", $word_array );
            $w          = '';

            shuffle( $words );

            foreach ( $words as $word ){
                $w .= $word . ' ';
            }

            $element = $article->innertext = $w;

        }

        $output .= $article->outertext;

    }

    $html = $output;

    return $html;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
function shuffle($text){
 $text_array = array_shuffle(explode(" ",$text)); 
 $text_string = implode($text_array," ");
 return $text_string;
}
```